# How to combine PhraseQuery with RangeQuery in Apache Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

Basically, I want to be able to query the index with the following query `"phrase query" AND date:[20180101 TO 20181231]`. I've tried using the `MultiFieldQueryParser`, but got the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: field "date" was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery`

So I constructed the query using the code as follows:

```
final Query phraseQ = new QueryParser("text", Analyzer.CUSTOM)
        .parse(query);
final Query rangeQ = new QueryParser("date", Analyzer.CUSTOM)
        .parse(dateRange);

final Query q = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
        .add(phraseQ, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
        .add(rangeQ, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
        .build();
```

where query is `"phrase query"~1` and dateRange is `date:[20180101 TO 20181231]`. I still get the following exception

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: field "date" was indexed without position data; cannot run PhraseQuery (phrase=date:"phrase query"~1)`

although I don't query the date field with a phrase.

Are phrase queries combined with range queries at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

MultiFieldQueryParser is designed to search in all of the list of fields given whenever a field is not specified in the query. So, this:

```
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[] {"text","date"}, new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = parser.parse("\"phrase query\" AND date:[20180101 TO 20181231]");
```

Produces a query that looks like this:

```
+(text:"phrase query" date:"phrase query") +date:[20180101 TO 20181231]
```

Thus the problem. If you replace it with just the standard `QueryParser`, with "text" as the default field, it should produce what you want.

---

As far as the code you've provided, however, it looks fine. Try printing the contents of `dateRange` just before parsing it, make sure it is what you think it is.